# How to render duplicate elements by using `React.createRef()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my below code I want to render duplicate elements by using `React.createRef()`. because in the long run, I have to render the same element in the dialog for the help screen.

So how can I render it in DOM?

By the below code, I can get ref of the `div` element but cant renders it in Dom.

```
export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {};
    myRef;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div ref={this.myRef}>
                    <h2>Hello World!!!</h2>
                </div>
                {this.myRef && <>{this.myRef.current}</>}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Edit:

I have to pass this reference to a new component(`HelpScreenComponent`), which will render same element along with some extra UI as a Dialog.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the proper use case for refs. Is there any reason why you can't pass referenced element as a separate component to other parts of your app?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. If you need to reuse something, it should be its own component.

Comment: Dom reference is not a valid react component

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov  I have to pass this reference to a new component(`HelpScreenComponent`), which will render same component along with some extra UI element as a Dialog.

Comment: @RaviSevta: you can save your brand new `<Hello />` component in a separate file and import wherever it is needed. You may customize its look and behavior using props. Breaking large UI structures into small reusable pieces is the whole idea of React (not messing around with refs).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was to render duplicate components on overlay for first-time users to display them a help screen.

I got not the exact answer but solution to my problem by rending only inner Html.

In the above code by replacing line

```
{this.myRef && <>{this.myRef.current}</>}
```

with this

```
{this.myRef.current && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.myRef.current.innerHTML}}/>}
```